# How preserve values in PHP when the page was refreshed?

Tags: php, class, oop, session, static

For example:

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    public static $my_static = 0;

    public function staticValue() {
        echo self::$my_static++;
    }
}
$a = new Foo();
$b = new Foo();
$a->staticValue();
$b->staticValue();

?>
```

After the code executed, the result was 01. But after I refresh the page, the result is still 01. I want to know how to modify the code to obtain the result is 23 when I refresh the page. Thank you in advance.

Comment: save the previous result in session then pass in after every refresh page

Comment: use $_SESSION. not static

Comment: What do you mean by refreshing? It will be good if you provide any scenario. Because if you simply wanna do page refresh the whole script gets loaded again.

Answer (score 4):

If you want preserve your values you can use sessions like this:

```
<?php

session_start();

class Foo
{
    public static $my_static;

    public function staticValue() {
        if(!isset($_SESSION['sum'])) {
          $_SESSION['sum'] = 0; 
        }

        self::$my_static = $_SESSION['sum'];
        echo self::$my_static++;
        $_SESSION['sum'] = self::$my_static;
    }
}
$a = new Foo();
$b = new Foo();
$a->staticValue();
$b->staticValue();

?>
```

Read more in:

> http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php